# Windows 10/11: Desktop shortcut with hotkey: Long delay running item? (about 3 seconds)

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a powershell script hanging off a desktop icon. The icon has a global hotkey assigned.

The startup command in the shortcut is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\develop\utils\fetchlatest.ps1
```

I notice a three second delay for the item to start.

Is there a way to improve this? (the script takes about 2 seconds to run, so the startup delay is quite noticeable.)

Comment: you may wan to add `Start-Transcript` to the top of your script. that should let you know what is going on ... and it has time stamps. [*grin*] ///// also, you may wan to try adding `-NoProfile` to your command. that will stop anything in your various profiles from loading.